# CMS Made Simple show all news with sub-categories

Tags: smarty, cmsmadesimple

Is there a way to tell CMS Made Simple to show news that are under a specific category this way by typing `{news category="Main Category 1"}` ?

So it would print news that belong to Main Category 1 like this:

```
- Sub Category 1 Name -
News 1 name
News 2 name
News 3 name

- Sub Category 2 Name -
News 1 name
.
.
.
```

and so on.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

{news number=4' detailpage="event-news" summarytemplate="main" category="latest news, deals"}

here is some example, for your case, i think you need

{news category="Main Category 1"}
{news category="Main Category 2"}
and so on.

1. you need to create the category in the news module first then create
2. news and choose your category when, before or after you publish.

thanks for reading